# Airflow glue job

Tags: python, airflow, parameter-passing, aws-glue

I want to be able to pass the glue arguments in the airflow instead of script. I am trying like below but it doesn't work:

Comment: Why do you have an equal sign in your return statement?

Comment: What is `glueJob` short for? What statement defined it?

Comment: You are using `airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.glue.GlueJobHook`?

Comment: Pretty sure `AwsGlueJobHook` is deprecated.

Comment: Can you please give me the statement that you used to create `glueJob`? Also the result of `print(type(glueJob))`.

Comment: Thanks. Strange. I think I would need more information/code to answer your question. I need to see exactly what you are running. Perhaps you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No need to share the whole project (and don't), just try to replicate this error with as little code as possible. This will increase your chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you shared indicates that you are running older version of the Amazon provider.

For this to work you must have `apache-airflow-providers-amazon>=2.3.0`.

Usage Example:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.glue import GlueJobHook

some_run_kwargs = {"NumberOfWorkers": 5}
some_script_arguments = {"--var1": "value"}
glue_job_hook = GlueJobHook(
    job_name='aws_test_glue_job',
    desc='This is test case job from Airflow',
    iam_role_name='my_test_role',
    script_location="s3:/glue-examples/glue-scripts/sample_aws_glue_job.py",
    s3_bucket="my-includes",
    region_name="us-west-2",
)
glue_job_run = glue_job_hook.initialize_job(
    script_arguments=some_script_arguments,
    run_kwargs=some_run_kwargs
)
```

If you are using `apache-airflow-providers-amazon<2.3.0` you can create a custom hook by backporting the code added in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16796):

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.glue import AwsGlueJobHook

class MyGlueJobHook(AwsGlueJobHook):
    
    def initialize_job(
        self,
        script_arguments: Optional[dict] = None,
        run_kwargs: Optional[dict] = None,
    ) -> Dict[str, str]:
        """
        Initializes connection with AWS Glue
        to run job
        :return:
        """
        glue_client = self.get_conn()
        script_arguments = script_arguments or {}
        run_kwargs = run_kwargs or {}

        try:
            job_name = self.get_or_create_glue_job()
            job_run = glue_client.start_job_run(JobName=job_name, Arguments=script_arguments, **run_kwargs)
            return job_run
        except Exception as general_error:
            self.log.error("Failed to run aws glue job, error: %s", general_error)
            raise
```

Then you can use `MyGlueJobHook` as above.